# When should I terminate MPI child processes?

Tags: c++, mpi

I am implementing an algorithm in C++ with MPI. There are a number files to be processed. Here is my design:

```
int main()
{
  MPI_Init();
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nproc);

  MPI_Barrier(..);
  if(my_rank == 0)
  {
    for (each file to be processed)
      {
         Read in file content;
         MPI_Send data to child processes;
         process partial data on root process;
         MPI_Recv data processed by child processes;
         combine processed data from root and children;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      MPI_Recv data from root;
      process received data;
      MPI_Send processed data to root;
      MPI_Finalize();
    }

//only root process reaches here
MPI_Finalize();

}
```

The program runs perfectly when there is only one file to process. However if I have more than 1 file to deal with, it will stuck at the second file. And it appears no child process is available to receive new data from root. I think this is because I terminate the child processes after processing the first file. But if I comment out the MPI_Finalize() in the else block, the program will quit after processing the first data file with the error:

```
mpirun has exited due to process rank 1 with PID 2003 on
node c301-115 exiting improperly. There are three reasons this could occur:

1. this process did not call "init" before exiting, but others in
the job did. This can cause a job to hang indefinitely while it waits
for all processes to call "init". By rule, if one process calls "init",
then ALL processes must call "init" prior to termination.

2. this process called "init", but exited without calling "finalize".
By rule, all processes that call "init" MUST call "finalize" prior to
exiting or it will be considered an "abnormal termination"

3. this process called "MPI_Abort" or "orte_abort" and the mca parameter
orte_create_session_dirs is set to false. In this case, the run-time cannot
detect that the abort call was an abnormal termination. Hence, the only
error message you will receive is this one.
```

Is there a way to reset MPI instance for children process in this case and where is the best place to finalize child processes?

Comment: MPI_Finalize does not cause a program to exit. Your worker processes will actually call that function twice, which may have unintended results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a second for loop for the workers to wait for new assignments so that they don't terminate immediately.

Think of It like this: You have N people working at the same time. You somehow decided, that one of them, the one with name "0" has the special job of assigning jobs to all of the others. You gave an exact specification of what everyone is supposed to do. The code you wrote looks like this in your code this means

```
for(file in files)
   send job
```

For the guy with the name "0" and

```
process one job
```

for all the others. What you want the others to do is:

```
for(file in files)
   process job
```

That should be reflected in your code, which could look similar to this:

```
int main()
{
  MPI_Init();
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nproc);

  MPI_Barrier(..);
  if(my_rank == 0)
  {
    for (each file to be processed)
      {
         Read in file content;
         MPI_Send data to child processes;
         process partial data on root process;
         MPI_Recv data processed by child processes;
         combine processed data from root and children;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      for (each file to be processed)
        {
          MPI_Recv data from root;
          process received data;
          MPI_Send processed data to root;
          MPI_Finalize();
        }
    }

  //only root process reaches here
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

**sidenote:** What is the benefit of the extremely hierarchical structure you are proposing? Wouldn't it be better if each worker thread works on its own file?

Comment: If the data processing function is serial, then it is totally fine to process multiple files at the same time. But in my case, the function itself is implemented with MPI.

Comment: The for loop in root process makes more sense since it reads in one file each iteration. However, the child processes do not deal with files directly. All they do is receiving data from root, process, and send data back to root. So it would be kind of tricky to break up into several iterations. In other words, the i in for loop or root may not necessarily map to the i in for loop for child.

Comment: is there any better strategy than the for loop?

Comment: @MrWhite you could put the `if` inside the `for`-loop. That would make it clearer that the root and workers are *in sync* as hammar puts it

Answer (score 0):

Remember that your processes need to stay "in sync". That is, for every send there should be a receive and so on, so you'll need to have a loop in the child processes just like you have in the root process.

One way of doing this is to at the beginning of the program, have the root process send the number of files to be processed to all the child processes. Then have them loop as many times as the root process does.

Comment: I guess a little context about my algorithm might help. I am trying to implement a recursive mergesort algorithm with MPI which will be applied for external sort. That's why I can read the whole file all at once into memory. The root process divides the array to be sorted to two halves, the left half will be handled by the same process while the right half gets sent to a child process and sorted there. Once it is sorted on a child process, that half is sent back to root and merged with the other half that is sorted on the same process. (to be continued)

Comment: (continuing..) In my main function, for both rank==0 and else block, my main sort function mergesort_mpi will be called. Depending on the rank of the process and available number of processors, the program will decide whether to sort the array allocated sequentially or proceed to the next iteration. In my mergesort_mpi function, there are MPI_Send and MPI_Recv commands. Overall the sends match recvs.

Comment: I think my question is. If I have another for loop for child processes, how do I make sure a child process is receiving data from the corresponding data set defined by i in the for loop of root process?

Comment: @MrWhite: As long as the send and receive operations happen in the same order on both processes, everything's fine. But if you want to make sure, you can pass `i` as the `tag` parameter of MPI_Send/Recv.